# Show two copies of same menu

Tags: 7, routes, blocks

Let's say I have Main Menu and I want to show it in header and in footer, to achieve that I can use Menu Block module, but using it lets say I disable one link in Main Menu, it also disables it in the clone menu in the footer. How do I have multiple copies of same menu, but with different disable options for each, and when adding new links it would update both, but at the same time be able to disable links separately on each menu?

Let's say both menus have Home and Events links. I want to show Home and Events in just header menu and disable Events in footer? And if I decide to add new link, it will add up in both menus at the same time and then again I will be able to disable it in only one of them if needed.

Makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I have multiple copies of same menu, but with different disable options for each

Drupal doesn't support anything like that, and I must admit it doesn't make sense to me that it would.

As soon as you have two menus that need to show different things, you need two menus. Setting arbitrary rules on how that second menu should partially sync itself with another, arbitrary, menu, is a conceptual nightmare. I can't even imagine what the UI would look like for that.